# Why doesn't pressing enter return '\n' to getch()?

Tags: c, input

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
    char ch,name[20];
    int i=0;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter a string:");
    while((ch=getch())!='\n')
    {
        name[i]=ch;
        i++;
    }
    name[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s",name);
}
```

When I give "abc" as input and if I press enter it's not working. Can anyone let me know why the condition ch=getch() != '\n' is not becoming false when I press enter? I have also observed that ch is taking \r instead of \n. Kindly let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Use '\r' and **terminate your string with '\0'.**

Additionally, you might try to use getche() to give a visual echo to the user and do some other general corrections:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 20

int main()
{
    char ch, name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    int i=0;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter a string:");
    while ( ((ch=getche())!='\r') && (i < MAX_NAME_LENGTH - 1) )
    {
        name[i]=ch;
        i++;
    }
    name[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's a formatting issue, but you meant to terminate with null - "\0", right...

Comment: Yes, for chars, '\0', NULL and 0 mean the same, but using '\0' makes it more clear, agreed and corrected.

Comment: As long a you're correcting things, you might want to cap that while loop at 19 iterations, make main() explicitly "int main(void)", flush stdout after the prompting printf(), and return a value.

Answer (score 6):

Try \r instead of \n

\n is the new line character (0x0A) or 10 decimal, \r is the carrige return character (0x0D) or 13 decimal.

The return key is a carrige return.

Answer (score 4):

The keyboard return key is the carriage return, or CR.  This is found by running the program and analyzing the results.

When you press enter key, the ASCII value of Enter key is not returned, instead CR is returned.

Hence `(ch=getch())!='\n'` should be changed to any of the following equivalent statements:

```
ch=getch())!='\r' 
ch=getch())!=13     // ASCII for CR: decimal
ch=getch())!=0xd     // hexadecimal for CR
ch=getch())!=0xD     // hexadecimal for CR
ch=getch())!=015     // octal for CR
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can use the `{}` option in the toolbar to format your code snippets for better readability.

Answer (score 1):

on some system the newline is "\r\n" carriage return (enter) is "\r"

Answer (score 1):

That is because the return key on your keyboard is represented internally as '\r' not '\n'.  In order for that specific example to work, you would need to trap '\r' instead.

Answer (score 0):

An enter is actually "\r\n" (carriage return and line feed) on Windows. getchar() will return '\n' I think.

Answer (score 0):

The actual meaning of `\n` is `\r`+`\n`. `getch()` function reads a character from the keyboard.
It does not echo it and does not wait for next character.
So whenever we enter `\n` character `getch()` function reads `\r` character only.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch,name[20];
    int i=0;
    printf("Enter a string:");
    while(1)
    {
      ch = getch();
      if(ch==13) //enter ASCII value
      {
        name[i]='\0';
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        name[i]=ch;
        i++;
        printf("*");
      }
    }
    printf("%s",name);
    return 0;
}
```

you can also add the feature of backspace by simply adding

```
else if(ch==8) //ASCII value of Backspace
 {
   if(i>0)
   {
     i--;
     printf("\b \b");
   }
 }
```

to the if else statement

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be better to simply use:

```
scanf("%19s", name);
```

instead of getch thing.

Comment: when using while you can get the same buffer overflow if you don't control value of i. what's the difference?

Comment: @Alnitak: i updated the code to prevent buffer overflow, you thought about that or is there anything wrong with scanf?

Comment: `scanf("%19s", name);` will not work for names with spaces in them,

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your system. Also you must know that *getch()* it's a part of the XSI Curses Standard issued by X-Open or OpenGroup and not related to the Borland specific *conio.h* header.

You must use **getchar(3)** or **getc(3)**, which all of them belong to the *[ISO/IEC 9899:1990](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)* standard. Both calls retreives just one byte from the controlling terminal/console or the input stream, respectively.

If you are calling them from a Windows platform, you retreive with the Enter key, the *'\r', '\n'* sequence, instead of just '\n'. Then you must create a loop arround the **getchar(3)** or **getc(3)** calls. Also, a call to **fgets(3)** over *stdin* would work to obtain the *'\r', '\n'* sequence.

Another point, is that some platforms needs flush the *stding* stream, then you must apply the **fflush(3)** call to the *stdin* stream.

**fgets(3)** and **fflush(3)** belongs to the *ISO/IEC 9899:1990* standard.