# regarding inputing enter key

Tags: c, ascii, enter

```
char ch;
ch=getch();
printf("%d",ch);
```

When I input `enter key` then the output displayed is

```
13
```

But ascii code for new line is 10, so why 13 is displayed?

The following code runs infinite time on inputting `enter key`

```
char *ch=malloc(100);
do
{
    *ch=getch();
     ch++;
}while(*(ch-1)!='\n');
```

Comment: `getch` is non-standard and non-portable. Please use `getchar` instead.

Answer (score 2):

In some systems, "Enter" is really two characters: Carriage Return followed by Line Feed.

Comment: If this is the case then how to check the condition of `'\n'`

Comment: @zee After reading your update, and as mentioned by Paul, getch is non-Standard. If you really must use it, then you already know that it returns returns `'\r'` on "Enter", so check against that instead. If not, you can always use getchar().

Answer (score 1):

End-of-line is always represented by `'\n'` in C, regardless of whether the underlying system represents it as `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`, or something else. The value of `'\n'` is probably 13 on your system.

C doesn't require ASCII, but ASCII has a carriage return character and a line feed character. Don't use the numeric values for any of them, since C doesn't require ASCII - always use the character literal `'\n'` for portability.

`getch()` is not a standard C function, so who knows what you're trying to do with it, but when using the C standard I/O, library, you're testing for end of line, not for some specific key like <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and you do that by testing for `'\n'`. Obviously if you're using those functions on a file, it wouldn't make any sense to talk about keys.

Comment: check my updated question and you will know what I am trying to do with `getch()`

Comment: What I mean is, I have no idea what `getch()` does or how it works, since it's not a standard C function, and you give no details about it. Perhaps it doesn't work for you because that function doesn't read characters at all, for all I know.

Comment: You'll need to tell me, it's your function. The only `getch()` function I'm familiar with is the one in the ncurses library. I understand there were some obsolete Borland compilers that supported another function of the same name, on a time.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using Windows OS. When you press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, then `'\r'` character also called `carriage return` or `CR` is read by the `getch` function. See [key-codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#vk_clear). You are comparing this with the newline character `'\n'` which obviously evaluates to `false` and you continue looping. So you should do this instead:

```
char *ch = malloc(100);

// check ch for NULL
do {
    *ch = getch();
     ch++;
} while(*(ch-1) != '\r');  // compare with carriage return
```

ASCII value of `'\r'` is 13 and that explains your output.`getch` function is not standard and not portable. Also, it has been deprecated. You should use the standard `getchar` function  instead. Additionally, read this - [Why doesn't pressing enter return '\n' to getch()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473661/why-doesnt-pressing-enter-return-n-to-getch)