# end a C program loop when Enter key is pressed

Tags: c

I'm working on an input validation program in C. I have a function called `show_password` which accepts users input ranging from 8- 13 characters.
The code is now only allowing user to enter until 13 characters so as to quit.
I need to quit the program whenever a user presses `enter` for characters between 8-13 characters.

I have defined a macro:

```
#define PASSWORD_LENGTH 13
```

Here is my code

```
// password
void _password()
{

    char pass_word[PASSWORD_LENGTH];

    printf("\nEnter 8-13 character Password\n");
    for (j=0; j<=PASSWORD_LENGTH; j++)           //at this code is where i need to make the change
    {
        pass_word[j] = getch();     // Hidden password
        printf("*");
    }
    pass_word[j] = '\0';
    printf("\n");
    printf("password entered is:");
        for (j=0; pass_word[j] != '\0'; j++ )
    {
        printf("%c",pass_word[j]);

    }
    getch();

}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to compare the character read to `'\n'`, and if that's what it is, to `break` out of the loop?

Comment: Also, why in the world would you use a loop to print the result character by character?  You've added a terminator, so it is well positioned to be printed all at once as a string.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i had a sleep() function included that is the reason I needed to print it character by character

Comment: Is the the complete code? j is undefined.

Comment: And when j == PASSWORD_LENGTH you're running past the end of your pass_word buffer.

Comment: Your loop is running one iteration too many.  The loop test needs to be `j < PASSWORD_LENGTH`.  The array is also too short.  The posted code writes two characters past the end of the array.  With the above fix, it will still write one character past the end.

Comment: @PaulLynch yes I've defined j as a global variable

Comment: @Tittoh I've updated the answer, could you check if that's the behaviour you're looking for?

Comment: In the title, you probably mean "end the input loop" instead of "quit a C program". Please consider editing the question changing the title and the description of what you want to happen...

Comment: @mikyll98 yes ive checked the answer ive also got a link to a  [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473661/why-doesnt-pressing-enter-return-n-to-getch)

Comment: What should happen if the password is less than 8 characters long. Should the `ENTER` key be ignored? Or should the program quit with an error message instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- check if the character read from input is equal to `'\n'` or `'\r'` to detect when the user enters `RETURN`;
- check if the index is greater or equal 8 (which means the user is pressing enter as 9th character or after);
- use `break` keyword to quit the loop.

Example:

```c
pass_word[j] = getch();
if ((pass_word[j] == '\n' || pass_word[j] == '\r') && j >= 8)
    break;
```

Comment: @AndreasWenzel The master should try to see farther than the apprentice. `:-)`

Comment: On the other hand, it is unclear from the question what should happen if the password is less than 8 characters long. Should the `ENTER` key be ignored? Or should the program quit with an error message instead? I have asked OP for clarification.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Actually I think we shouldn't encourage users to write unclear questions by giving answers which try to find the hidden meaning, because if it's hard to understand for an expert, then it'll be even harder to understand for a casual/generic user... But I see your point of view

Comment: The FIRST comment under the OP did "reinterpret" the meaning, but without comment to correct the phrasing of the title or the actual question. There are days, eh? `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

getch() returns the ASCII value of the key pressed by the user as an input, enter key is a carriage return .When you press enter key, the ASCII value of Enter key is not returned, instead carriage return (CR) is returned.

`\r` is used as a carriage return character representing the return or `enter` key on keyboard
[similar stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473661/why-doesnt-pressing-enter-return-n-to-getch)

This code worked

```
// password
void _password()
{

    char pass_word[PASSWORD_LENGTH];

    printf("\nEnter 8-13 character Password\n");
   for (j=0; j<=PASSWORD_LENGTH; j++)
    {

        pass_word[j] = getch();
        printf("*");
        if (pass_word[j] == '\n' || pass_word[j] == '\r')
        break;
        
          // Hidden password

    }

    pass_word[j] = '\0';
    printf("\n");
    printf("password entered is:");
        for (j=0; pass_word[j] != '\0'; j++ )
    {
        printf("%c",pass_word[j]);

    }
    getch();

}
```

Comment: Buffer overrun for long entry??? and minimum of 8 chars??

Comment: @Fe2O3: You may want to elaborate on your comment. I doubt that OP will understand what you mean.

Comment: To elaborate on the comment by @Fe203: The line `for (j=0; j<=PASSWORD_LENGTH; j++)` should probably be `for (j=0; j<PASSWORD_LENGTH; j++)`, because otherwise in the line `pass_word[j] = getch();`, you will be accessing the array `pass_word` out of bounds.

Comment: To further elaborate on the comment by @Fe2O3: In your question, you stated that the password should be at least 8 characters long. However, your posted solution does not seem to enforce this requirement.

Comment: "This code worked"... This code did not test for minimum entry (8), and this code iterates for long entry until the 13 byte buffer (addressable elements 0 to 12) is "overrun", illegally accessing memory beyond the declared buffer size... This code is insufficient (min length) and may invoke UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR... (written for @AndreasWenzel)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Sorry, but there is SO MUCH that has been (and still is) wrong with the OP that it is SO frustrating trying to provide assistance. (The question still states "I have a function called show_password" where, clearly this is not the case...) Some days one could simply SCREAM!!! .. All good `:)`